# Trying to concatanate non-consistant data within range

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I am working with python. I'm trying to partition a set of data into 1000 element ranges and find the average, including sites that are not present as 0.0.

Below is a sample of the data.

`X  2699528 0.000786782
X   2699555 0.493415
X   2699559 0.000786782
X   2699625 0.0748873
X   2699645 0.0712507
X   2699664 0.000786782
X   2699676 0.400653
X   2699683 0.0109586
X   2699711 0.000786782
X   2699739 0.00157294
X   2699906 0.0617229
X   2699919 0.000786782
X   2699934 0.000786782
X   2699968 0.498501
X   2700027 0.499971
X   2700040 0.000786782
X   2700089 0.0101799
X   2700147 0.000786782
X   2700157 0.0719793
X   2700185 0.00314341
X   2700189 0.000786782`

I want the data to look like:

```
X 2700000 average1
X 2701000 average2
....
```

The problem is that there isn't a consistent number within each range. Some ranges might have zero elements in that range. Also I don't want simply an average, but an average with the sites that are not included too. Basically, if I have

```
X 1 10
X 3 10
X 5 10
X 7 10
X 9 10
```

I don't want to return 10 as the average, but 5 (five 0's and five 10's).

The following is my code.

```
import sys

sum = 0.0
startin = 2700000

for i in range(2700, 155000):
        m = (i * 1000) + 1000
        i = i * 1000
        for line in sys.stdin:
                data =line.strip().split('\t')
                if data[0] == "CHROM":
                        continue
                if int(data[1]) >= i and int(data[1]) <= m:
                        sum += float(data[2])
        print i, (sum/1000)
        continue
```

Which returns

```
2700000 0.002568799204
2701000 0.002568799204
2702000 0.002568799204
2703000 0.002568799204
2704000 0.002568799204
2705000 0.002568799204
2706000 0.002568799204
2707000 0.002568799204
2708000 0.002568799204
2709000 0.002568799204
2710000 0.002568799204
2711000 0.002568799204
2712000 0.002568799204
2713000 0.002568799204
2714000 0.002568799204
2715000 0.002568799204
2716000 0.002568799204
2717000 0.002568799204
2718000 0.002568799204
2719000 0.002568799204
2720000 0.002568799204
2721000 0.002568799204
2722000 0.002568799204
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: so... whats the problem? its not the quickets approach but seems like you get what you wanted

Comment: All the averages are different, but it only printed the one for the first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of iterating over the entire data set for each possible range, you can just use integer division to assign all values to buckets in a single iteration.

```
buckets = defaultdict(float)
bucket_size = 1000

for line in lines:
    index,value = line.split()
    buckets[int(index)/bucket_size] += float(value)

for k,v in sorted(buckets.items()):
    print k,v/bucket_size
```